# Select and Deselect the checkboxs using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery and I have below HTML with checkboxes in it.

```
 <div class="selectallitems">
                    <div class="selectall">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" CssClass="selectall-txt" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divCheckAll">
                        <div class="selectall">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItemLists" CssClass="selectall-txt-1" runat="server" />
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="selectall">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkComponentLinks" CssClass="selectall-txt-1" runat="server" />
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="selectall">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkResourceKeyData" CssClass="selectall-txt-1" runat="server" /></div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now I want whenever user selects "chkSelectAll" then it should select all other checkboxes and whenever user deselect any of them it should deselect the "chkSelectAll".

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would basically do something like this:

```
$('#myCheckAllCheckbox').click(function()
{
     // Other jQuery versions:
     if(this.checked)
        $('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
     else
        $('input[@type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');

     // jQuery 1.6
     $('input[@type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but you should change the selector to `".selectall-txt-1"` since that seems made for that purpose.

Comment: You can also do something like this: `$('#<%= chkSelectAll.ClientID.ToString() %>').click(...)`

Comment: `$('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);` will work

Comment: What is "#myCheckAllCheckbox"? I don't have anything like this.

Comment: Hi Guys above code is just selecting the child checkboxes, however I need to deselect the parent checkbox if any of the child check is deselected